# How to serialize a map of pointers in boost library?

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to **serialize** a **map of pointers**.

**Map creation**:

```
float *data = new float[1000];
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, float*> > mapa;
mapa[4]["foo"] = data;
```

**Serialize map to file**:

```
std::ofstream ofs("somefile");
boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
oa<<mapa;
ofs.close();
```

**Loading map from file:**

```
std::ifstream ifs("somefile", std::ios::binary);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, float*> > newMapa;
ia >> newMapa;
ifs.close();
```

How can I do it properly?

Example with compilation errors:
https://godbolt.org/z/76fMbxMhf

Comment: How do you expect the pointer to be serialized? Should it just serialize the address held in the pointer, pointing to nothing when being deserialized? There is no information about the size of the pointed array accessible through the map.

Comment: We could assume that the size of the pointed array is always 1000.

Comment: Is there any part of boost library which can deal with serialization of those kind of structures? I can rephrase my question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say for sure. If the pointer cannot be replaced by some type with ownership semantics (`std::array`/`std::vector`), I would just wrap the `float*` in a class which I can give the correct `serialize` member.

Comment: In my case I have over a dozen structures: map of pointers. Each pointer is initialized by `cudaAlloc`, I would like to avoid additional overlay.

Comment: I'm with @user17732522 if you must have the raw pointer (from your code it seems like you do not, because you never even serialize the data themselves?)

Answer (score 0):

The strong typedef has been designed to wrap primitives into trackable types: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(float, Float)
```

However this will introduce considerable (!) overhead, because every single element needs tracking. In your example, it would make 1000x more sense to replace the pointer with the array index.

While you're at it, replace it with `std::vector<float>` so you don't have lifetime issues (and leaks).

Finally, make sure the archive is complete before you close the file or even read from it again.

### Take #1

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1ec2e733fbf00ab)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

using ConvolutedIndex = std::map<int, std::map<std::string, size_t>>;

int main()
{   
    auto data = std::vector<float>(1000);
    std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0); // fill with sample data

    float* element = &data[rand() % data.size()]; // pick random element

    std::cout << "Random pick: " << *element << " at " << element << "\n";

    {
        std::ofstream                   ofs("filename", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << ConvolutedIndex{
            {4,
             {
                 {"foo", element - data.data()},
             }},
        };
    } // also closes file, but more importantly, completes archive first

    {
        std::ifstream                   ifs("filename", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

        ConvolutedIndex newMapa;
        ia >> newMapa;

        std::cout<< "The element recovered: " << data.at(newMapa.at(4).at("foo")) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Random pick: 383 at 0x1f142dc
The element recovered: 383
```

### Take #2

That still has problems, because you never serialized the floats being indexed. Easily remedied:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb6e4f3eb59f8370)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

using Data            = std::vector<float>;
using ConvolutedIndex = std::map<int, std::map<std::string, size_t>>;

int main()
{   
    {
        Data data(1000);
        std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0); // fill with sample data

        float* element = &data[rand() % data.size()]; // pick random element
        std::cout << "Random pick: " << *element << " at " << element << "\n";

        std::ofstream                   ofs("filename", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

        oa << data << ConvolutedIndex{
            {4,
             {
                 {"foo", element - data.data()},
             }},
        };
    } // also closes file, but more importantly, completes archive first

    {
        std::ifstream                   ifs("filename", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

        Data            newData;
        ConvolutedIndex newMapa;
        ia >> newData >> newMapa;

        std::cout<< "The element recovered: " << newMapa.at(4).at("foo") << "\n";
    }
}
```

Now everybody's happy (well, except the [Gods of `<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), but something needs to be the exercise for the reader):

```
Random pick: 383 at 0x1bd930c
The element recovered: 383
```